# Android parsing String to Date with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android

I have String dateOrder= '2014-09-28' , i want to change format with SimpleDateFormat. but this is cannot formated.. how to solve ?
this my code

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        String dateOrder = fill_order_in.get(Variabel.KEY_DATE_ORDER);
        try {
            Date d = date.parse(dateOrder);
            dateOrder = date.format(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: 2014-09-28 is not `"dd/MM/yy"`.

Comment: yes, but i want result that .. so how the trick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the first line to

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You can use this for the `parse`. Then you need another `SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy")` for formatting the new version.

The key point is that the parsing needs to be done with one pattern, and the formatting needs to be done with another. So rather than just creating one `SimpleDateFormat` instance, you need two, with different patterns: one for parsing, and one for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this:

```
    //first create an object that will parse your date as you have it ie 2014-09-28
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateOrder = fill_order_in.get(Variabel.KEY_DATE_ORDER);
    try {
        Date d = date.parse(dateOrder);
        //then use a different object to format the date as you want it ie 9/28/2014
        dateOrder = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").format(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```